# Getting internal server error in nginx if I upload Image

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

I running an app with uWSGI, nginx and falsk . 
When I run my server manually and upload image then it works fine but when i run my app as live with nginx then i am getting internal server error

My conf file is

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /srv/www/tmapi;
        set $home_dir "/srv/www/api/";
        client_max_body_size 12m;
        server_name x.x.com;
        access_log /srv/www/api/logs/nginx_access.log;
        error_log /srv/www/api/logs/nginx_error.log debug;

location /static/ {
    alias $home_dir/app/static/;
    access_log off;
    expires max;

}
location / { try_files $uri @app;}
location @app{
      include uwsgi_params;
      uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/analytics.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is probably a permission issue. You can change the owner of your folder to www-data if both nginx and your application run with this user.

Comment: nginx run as www-data owner

Comment: ls -l of my folder is 
drwxrwxrwx  5 www-data root 4096 Dec 21 09:07 app

Comment: i am getting log but there is no error i can give log too

Comment: I am having this same problem!  However, when i try the solution, nothing changes for me.  did the solution actually work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's simple folder permission problem. Just write this command to directory in which you want to save your file.

```
sudo chown www-data dir
```

It will make www-data as owner and www-data is running your nginx.